# How to model database tables for implementing Friend relationship?

Tags: database-design, social-networking

I'm trying to design a data model that denotes one user being the friend of another user.  This is what i've come up with so far, but it seems clunky, is there a better solution?

```
User
=====
Id
Name
etc...

UserFriend
===========
UserId
FriendId
IsMutual
IsBlocked
```

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807900/how-to-store-bidirectional-relationships-in-a-rdbms-like-mysql

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
UserRelationship
====
RelatingUserID
RelatedUserID
Type[friend, block, etc]
```

Agree that mutuality doesn't belong as a column; breaks normalization.

Comment: how abour adding status to 0 to 1 so that confirms that user has accepted b user ?

Comment: so then you need 2 rows per friendship, correct? e.g. Suppose `user1` friend-requests `user2` and `user2` accepts. You will need to insert 2 rows to present this: RelatingUserID: `user1` | RelatedUserID `user2` ------ RelatingUserID: `user2` | RelatedUserID `user1`

Comment: @mmcrae Right.  Each relationship modeled in this table is one-directional.

Comment: I am here now nine years later, could you please explain what do you mean by *breaks normalization*?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization.  Tracking the same relation using multiple redundant rows potentially exposes us to all the types of anomaly that normalization exists to prevent.

Answer (score 62):

To go **one record per two users** and avoid consuming extra memory that the proposed methods suggest (twice as much as needed, since there are two records for each user), you can do the following:

1. Table structure:

   ```
   USER_RELATIONSHIP {
       user_first_id,
       user_second_id,
       type

       primary key(user_first_id, user_second_id)
   }
   ```
2. Ensure: `user_first_id < user_second_id`
3. The most interesting part - `type`: for **all of the possible states** of a relationship, you create the corresponding values. For exmaple:

   ```
   pending_first_second
   pending_second_first
   friends
   block_first_second
   block_second_first
   block_both
   ```

What you have:

1. The `user_first_id < user_second_id` ensures that there is only one
   record of a relationship between two given users, since this and primary key constraints
   won't allow placing it otherwise.
2. By proper switching between the relationship states, you determine how each of two users relate to each other. If there is no relationship between two users, there is no record.
3. To find out the relationship between two users (as well as update), you simply go by a single query:

   ```
   select * from USER_RELATIONSHIP where
       user_first_id = user1_id and
       user_second_id = user2_id;
   ```

   without an `or` statement that would check this columns vice versa, which is faster.

**Example scenario**:

1. `no record` : are not in a relationship
2. `pending_first_second` : the first made a friend request to the second
3. `friends` : the second approved the friend request
4. `no record` : one of the users removed the other from his firends

This solution is efficient in terms of both memory and speed, because you create, store and update only one single record.

Comment: @artem But how to retrieve the friends from each user?

Comment: @nmfzone You simply query for all rows that contain the specified user in either of the id columns.

Comment: This is a great solution, about the only problem I could see is if you need to shard.  Relationship tables grow quite rapidly and often times need sharded. So if you do two rows per relationship then you can shared on the first user_id and when you query for all of the friends of a single user you can ensure you only need to check one shard.  Whereas if that user is in one column for some relationships and another for others, you would likely have to check all shards.

Comment: How to find mutual friends from it?

Comment: Thank you for this solution/concept. I looked at quite a few possible ways in the last hour and this is definitely one of the simplest and clearest ways while still being easy to manage and query.

Comment: what about just using `first_status` and `second_status` with values like `accepted, declined, blocked`

Comment: can you shad some light on what you mean by `user_first_id < user_second_id`, thanks

Comment: @Srle it's to ensure you don't have both (user_first_id, user_second_id) and (user_second_id, user_first_id) pairs stored in DB, instead of single record, otherwise everything is duplicated.

Comment: @ArtemNovikov do you mean ensuring it by some kind of constraint, where user_first_id value will always be less than user_second_id value such as:
`ALTER TABLE USER_RELATIONSHIP ADD CHECK (user_first_id < user_second_id);`. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I am currently building a social networking site for a client and I expressed things this way

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PersonFriend] (
    [Id]                          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp]                   DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    [ChangeUser]                  NVARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
    [FriendStatusId]              TINYINT        NOT NULL,
    [Person1Id]                   INT            NOT NULL,
    [Person2Id]                   INT            NOT NULL,
    [Person1RequestTimestamp]     DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    [Person2AcknowledgeTimestamp] DATETIME       NULL
);
```

Each person is stored in the Person table (imagine that). The Person1Id and Person2Id fields are FK to the person table. I keep a status list in the FriendStatus table for covering whether something has been request, accepted, denied, ignored etc. The Timestamp field is standard in my design to indicate record creation (it is a pattern thing that is used in by base persistence class) and its kind of duplicated in this table as the Person1RequestTimestamp contains the same data. I also capture when the Person2 saw the request and made an action (which gets indicated in FriendStatusId) on it and store that in the Person2AcknowledgeTimestamp).

One of the core assumptions of this design can be stated that Person1 requested friendship of Person2 - if that friendship is accepted then the friendship is considered mutual.

Comment: Looks nice - but what is that ChangeUser field?

Comment: Looks solid- I think it falls under the "activity" sort of friendship though.  i.e.: Friends are defined by the request for friendship, not the state of the friends.

Comment: ChangeUser is the username of the person who last changed this record, be it the person invoking its creation, accepting it or a site moderator making some change. It is intrinsic to the persistence pattern I am using

Comment: Question.... just curious, why would you not have the FriendStatus column in the same table?

Answer (score 5):

I'd do something similar to what you have, but remove the "IsMutual" flag.  Simply add a second row with inverse values when it is mutual.  It does add rows, but feels a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps add a Relationship table, put the relationship properties there, and reference it from UserFriend.

Answer (score 3):

Probably over the top but one can use the semantic web to model this. One can use the FOAF  (FOAF Friend of a Friend)-format.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I googled it but I'm not sure I got good results.  Do you have a link?

Comment: http://www.foaf-project.org/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOAF_(software). I have read about it in this book: http://www.amazon.com/Semantic-Web-Working-Ontologist-Effective/dp/0123735564/ref=pd_bbs_sr_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1229639606&sr=8-1

Answer (score 3):

I did it like this :

TABLE user

```
id  name
-----------
1   foo
2   roo
3   shoo
4   mooo
```

TABLE friend relation

```
id   u_id f_id
--------------
1    1    2
2    2    1
3    3    1
4    1    3
```

Everytime friend request accepted insert reverse manner `1 2 & 2 1` and simple query:

```
$ufq=mysql_query("SELECT t1.f_id,t2.id,t2.name FROM friends AS t1, user AS t2 WHERE t1.u_id='$u_id' AND t2.id=t1.f_id ORDER BY t2.name ")or die(mysql_error());
while($fn=mysql_fetch_array($ufq)){
    echo $fn["name"].'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you think about my solution?

You have 3 tables

```
1 **the user** (id,.etc)
2 **friend_request**(id,flaggerID,flaggedID)
3 **friend**(id,frienderID,friendedID)
```

You sign in, check if I'm in friend table, if yes list friends (I'm in friender>list friended) (I'm in friended>listfriender)

Do I have request? (Am I in flaggedID?) Know him? If not, delete record; if yes, create new record in request as me get putted in flagger and the flagger get in flagged. Now we have mutuality between 2 records in request table so we delete both and put them in friend table.
Easy to separate req/friends.

Answer (score 1):

Friendships are less clear cut than the classic employer/boss and user/spouse self-join scenarios. Is friendship a relationship or an activity? I've received a fair amount of criticism for neglecting the latter. Either way, you're probably going to need more than one table, no matter how generic your data model is.

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually need a physical table to discover if there are mutual friends? Why not do a SQL query like:

```
SELECT U.ID, U.NAME FROM USER U
INNER JOIN USERFRIEND UF
ON U.ID = UF.FRIENDID
WHERE U.ID = (SELECT USER.ID FROM USER
            WHERE USER.ID = friend_id AND USER.ID != your_id);
```

The query's results should return all of the mutual friends.

Comment: This question/answer is quite old. Anyway, I'd like to add that maybe a mutual relation is necessary for configuration. For example, you and me are friends but I'd like to see your notifications/new posts and you don't like to see mine. How do you solve it without reverse friendship?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm late to the party, but here is my bid.

First the tables:

```
User
-id

Type
-id

Relationship
-user_id_1
-user_id_2
-type_id
```

Now, I want to keep my type table simple. So the types that I add only represent a single user's relationship with another. They never represent the bidirectional relationship. For example:

```
friend
ignored
```

This makes adding new types easy. I don't have to think about or create all possible combinations of all my types. I just add the new type.

To setup a friendship, you would need 2 entries into the relationship table. If both users agree that they are friends, they are friends. If only one say he is friends with the other, and the other has him blocked, they are not friends.

Making queries is very simple. Here's how you get all the friends in MySQL:

```
SELECT u.* FROM user u
LEFT JOIN relationship r1 ON u.id = r1.user_id_2
LEFT JOIN relationship r2 ON u.id = r2.user_id_1
WHERE r1.user_id_1 = <my_user_id> # my relationship with them
AND r1.type_id = <friend_type_id> # i say i'm a friend
AND r2.user_id_2 = <my_user_id> # their relationship with me
AND r2.type_id = <friend_type_id> # they say they're friends
```

I also think this approach is more "transaction safe". Imagine you send a friend request to someone and then block that person afterwards. If that person later accept the friend request, it doesn't matter. It doesn't change the state of the relationship, because they are completely independent.

If you instead had a single type that represented the bidirectional relationship, you would be forced to make some sort of evaluation in your code, of what exactly the new state of the relationship should be, once the friend accepted the friend request. If you don't, you could end up unblocking a user and making that person friends with the user he or she had blocked.

I would much rather handle this on database-level. If you have a bunch of programmers working on the application it doesn't take long before someone forgets this issue somewhere and a hard-to-find bug is created.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding Friendship is  a result of a relation between two users (User1 and User2), and because a user1 can have 0 or many user(s) as friend(s) and vice-versa user2, therefore a junction table "Friend" commes in the middle to represent that relationship like this :

> User1 id(int) username(string)
>
> User2 id(int)  username(string)
>
> Friend
>   ---- id(int) user1_Id(int) user2_Id(int) active(bool)

Both user1_Id and user2_Id are FKs in Frind Table

I hope i am right.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should be create two table:

1. user
       u_id       int
       u_username string
       balahhh............

2. friendship
       fs_id        int
       relating_id  int
       related_id   int