# Database scheme design social networking sites

Tags: database-design, social-networking

Hi I am planning to design a social networking site (like orkut) asp.net mvc.I am stuck in database design.Anyone provide me the resource for that one.

Comment: Design your DB schema for you?!?

Comment: Very broad, can you narrow it some? Social networking sites are/can be beastly. And yeah, no one is going to want to build it for you but we can help you in the right direction.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379236/database-design-best-table-structure-for-capturing-the-user-friend-relationship

Answer (score 5):

These are the steps you should follow for initial database design.

First, list down all the "objects" you want to store, such as users, posts, relationships and so on.

Second, figure out, for each of those, *what* information you want to store (user name, password, full name, address, ...).

Then design your database tables following the third normal form.

1. Every column in a table should be an attribute of the key.
2. Every column in a table should be an attribute of the *entire* key.
3. Every column in a table should be an attribute of *only* the key.

Database design should *always* be done in third normal form, reverting to other forms *if* there is a performance problem *and* you understand the ramifications of reversion. You can generally do this safely (and efficiently) with the proper application of computed fields or triggers.

As an example, one thing you should *not* do is to try and model relationships in the users table. A row in that table will have the user name as the key and a relationship depends on *two* user names, so that would violate rule 3.

Comment: This is for relational databases. There are also other database models (NoSQL) which require a different approach

Answer (score 3):

Barry Williams hosts a library of free data models, which he offers as starting points for all sorts of applications.  His portfolio includes a suggested model for a social networking site; that page also includes links to some supporting information.  [Find out more.](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/social_networking/index.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You can figure out the fields/queries and everything else, but the basic tables are very simple:

- User Table
  Stores the User's Login/Password/Access Information
- User Info Table
  Stores the any additional data that the user might enter (Full Name, Birthday, etc)
- Relationship Table
  Stores the relationships between user A and User B
- Post Table
  Depending on what type of media your users will be posting in, this gives a list of all the messages posted, with a User ID attached

That is the basis of it and this layout is probably sufficent enough to mock Twitter (which is a very simple site).

Anything additional you should probably use your **brain** to figure out. It really isn't that hard. Facebook didn't become popular for creating a good database schema.

Answer (score 0):

There will be two main tables for user module i.e.

1. `tblUser(userId(P key)`, other detail columns)
2. `tblContacts(UserId(F key from tbluser),ContactId(F key from tbluser)` and both `userid` and `contactid` will be primary key, ie. composite key)