# What kind of database connection strategy should i use for a social networking site

Tags: php, database, mysqli, social-networking

i am planning on building a social networking site. I went through stack overflow for finding an answer [database connections for social networking site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489739/database-scheme-design-social-networking-sites). But it wasn't satisfying. I need to know what strategy should i follow to create a connection for the database for the social site i am building. (In case if there are lacks of users accessing the site). Strategies like singleton (but this is a bad idea,sice it would slow up after a large number of connections), Persistant connection - i am thinking of using persistant connection in mysqli. If it is not good then provide me a link or suggestion of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Choose whatever easy for you to develop and worry about the better strategy later. You won't know what is the better strategy if you haven't met the problem yet.

Comment: What you said would be more appropriate if i am developing a small scale site. and if i make a wrong decision then a lot of refactoring should be done later on in the code for the performance of the application

Comment: To be honest, I haven't never developed a large scale site. The largest site I am currently working only serve 500,000 page view per day. We have been successfully by starting small and polish it as we go. Currently, we are using MySQL and Memcache. I would suggest you to look at other successful architecture   
- [Facebook Secrets Of Web Performance](http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/4/23/facebook-secrets-of-web-performance.html)  
- [Facebook At 13 Million Queries ..](http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/11/4/facebook-at-13-million-queries-per-second-recommends-minimiz.html)