# confusion over relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, html

Hey guys I have a confusing question, I have a user table and it stores all the usual data for a user that you would expect but im trying to figure out how a user could add another user?

Sounds strange but each user in the User table has his own UI which is UserID how could I add another table where UserID can have a relationship with another UserID?

[image]

I will give the answer to those that could take the time to upload a table diagram and who can help with some examples for sqlsyntax related to this question, i.e how would I right the syntax for the above question if I wanted to display all the UserIDs friends on a page. How would I add a friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]You just need another table similar to the Pictures and wallposting table. You just need to be able to record many friend id's for one user id (one to many)

eg:

The query to then get friends would be:

```
DECLARE @UserID AS BIGINT

SET @UserID = 123

SELECT [friends].*
FROM [friends]
where [parentuserid]=@UserID#
```

to Insert a Friend:

```
DECLARE @UserID AS BIGINT
DECLARE @FriendID AS BIGINT

SET @UserID = 123
SET @FriendID = 321

INSERT INTO [Friends]
(
    [ParentUserID],
    [ChildUserID]
)
VALUES
(
    @UserID,
    @FriendID
)
```

Code to insert it example:

```
private void Test()
{
    string Query =
        @"INSERT INTO [Friends]
          (
            [ParentUserID],
            [ChildUserID]
          )
          VALUES
          (
            @UserID,
            @FriendID
          )";

    using ( SqlConnection oSqlConnection = new SqlConnection( "connect string" ) )
    {
        oSqlConnection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand oSqlCommand = new SqlCommand(Query,oSqlConnection))
        {
            oSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", Session["UserID"]);
            oSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FriendID", Session["FriendID"]);

            oSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Where would you get your friend ID from? what is the process for adding friends? do you search for them and select them from a list?

Comment: Is there a need for `FriendID`?

Comment: so ParentUserID is the current users id and childuserid is the persons userid your adding?

Comment: @Chris - No, but i always have a primary key on my tables.

Comment: @Garrith - yes, the parent UserID is the user that has the friends, the ChildUserID is the ID of the friend in the user table

Comment: still doesnt explain how I get the userid of the friend into the table?

Comment: @WraithNath the primary key would be composite `(ParentUserID, ChildUserID)`, it would enforce that you can't be friends twice, if indeed that is the case.

Comment: I use sessions for UserIDs so if I do a query on my database to bring back all the userids in my table and click on one of them it takes you to there page but how when i click the add friend do I differentiate the two UserIDs?

Comment: @Chris - I agree, I designed the database quickly in the designer to provide a screenshot. You obviously would not allow nulls either, its just an example. Thanks though

Comment: would it just be the case of INSERT INTO Friends Parentuserid, childuserid VALUES ("+ session.userid+", "unsure")

Comment: yeah chris this is what im struggling with what on earth do I set the childuserid to?

Comment: @Garrith - I have added more to the example. Where do you get your friends from? do you search for them and select one from a list?

Comment: yeah or from there own profile, it would mean I would have to add in FriendID into the user table assign it a number and either on my list or on there profile add in "somehow" a place to hold FriendID which would directly connect there UserID

Comment: similar to how a session currently holds the UserID of who is logged in

Comment: I would assume the current user ID is always in the session from the point you log in. If you then had a page where you searched for a user you could then call the method to insert the friend record passing the selected userID through to it. Or store the selected UserID in the session and then call the method reading it from the session. it really depends on how your site works, you could have it so clicking any other user in the system stores the friendID in session so you could call the method. Many possibilities!

Comment: How is UserID(logged in session) related to ParentUserID could I not just have this as UserID secondary key to User table?

Comment: The UserID in the session would be the ParentUserID in the friends table. The FriendID in the session would be the ChildUserID

Answer (score 2):

You just need a many to many relationship.

```
Create Table Friend(
  UserId int,
  FriendId int,
  Constraint pk_friends Primary Key (UserId, FriendId),
  Constraint fk_friend_user Foreign Key (UserId) References User(UserId),
  Constraint fk_friend_friend Foreign Key (FriendId) References User(UserId)
)
```

Comment: +1 This will require you to make a few further choices, do you insert two lines per friendship `userA, userB` and `userB, userA` for simplicity of joining or include a predicate in your join logic to make a single record work either way.  Also if choosing the first option are friendships automatically 2 way?

Comment: @Robb - good point. Is this like twitter where you can follow but the other person isn't required to follow back? Or is the relationship more like facebook where you confirm you are in fact friends and both parties are aware of the relationship? Not sure it changes my answer at all, but it does affect how you treat the data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a simple requirement of a User Referring Other user to join. If that is the case then you can simply have one more column `ReferenceUserID` in `User` Table and whenever a new user refers another user then simply add him with a `UserID` of referring user.  If he isn't a referred user then by default it will be `NULL`.

Later for retrieval you can use a Self Join.

**Update:**

For  Friend  (many to many relationship) you should look at following Question at StackOverflow

[Database design: Best table structure for capturing the User/Friend relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379236/database-design-best-table-structure-for-capturing-the-user-friend-relationship)

```
UserRelationship
====
RelatingUserID
RelatedUserID
Type[friend, block, etc]
```

A similar approach is used by Facebook where they have a kind of Cross join Table for relation between Friends.

Comment: I think he wants to be able to add friends, not just store what user referred them to the site. But it isn't totally clear. You are suggesting a 1:1 relationship, and I think he needs a many:many relationship.

Comment: OP's question wasn't clear... also many other answers explained the other aspect (m2m rel)so i didn't included that.

Answer (score 1):

Your asking a bit much with the diagrams etc.... for me at least.

It depends on the kind of relationship, one to one, it will be another Column in your user table. If it is many to many you'll need a junction table, with two columns UserIDA, UserIDB. Depending why you need the relationship.