# Best way to implement friends list into a database? MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, redis

So my project has a "friends list" and in the MySQL database I have created a table:

nameA

nameB

Primary Key (nameA, nameB)

This will lead to a lot of entries, but to ensure that my database is normalised I'm not sure how else to achieve this?

My project also uses Redis.. I could store them there.

When a person joins the server, I would then have to search for all of the entries to see if their name is nameA or nameB, and then put those two names together as friends, this may also be inefficient.

Cheers.

Comment: A may consider B a friend, while B considers A just an acquaintance. Do you want to consider this (i.e. each user can choose their friends) or do you only store pairs (A-B = B-A)?

Comment: I would not use a name as the primary key. What happens when two people named John Smith join?  Create a unique ID for each user use that as your primary key. You would then need another table that stores both userIDs as one record to show the relationship.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner B has to accept A's friendship in order to be put into the database, basically, each person needs a list of friends. Not sure how to put that into the database, this is what I came up with.

Comment: But could B accept A's friendship, but reject C's friendship? And if B rejected C's friendship, could C call B still a friend? This is something you must decide on. Shall A|B have another meaning as B|A or not?

Comment: This is similar to what you need.
Hope it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379236/database-design-best-table-structure-for-capturing-the-user-friend-relationship

Comment: @Zephyr in actual fact it's UUID, but I kept simplicity by using name. Sorry. Thorsten, if he rejects C's friendship, they are not friends.

Comment: @hellWarrior he basically has the same setup.

Comment: I had this request re-opened, because linked request is not a real duplicate, because there a relationsship has a direction, which yours has not.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thank you, shame that it's been closed as genuinely need help with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The task is quite common. You want to store pairs where A|B has the same meaning as B|A. As a table has columns, one of the two will be stored in the first column and the other in the second, but who to store first and who second and why?

One solution is to always store the lesser ID first and the greater ID second:

```
userid1 | userid2
--------+--------
1       | 2
2       | 5
2       | 6
4       | 5
```

This has the advantage that you store each pair only once, as feels natural, but has the disadvantage that you must look up a person in both coumns and find their friend sometimes in the first and sometimes in the second column. That may make queries kind of clumsy.

Another method is to store the pairs redundantly (by using a trigger typically):

```
userid1 | userid2
--------+--------
1       | 2
2       | 1
2       | 5
2       | 6
4       | 5
5       | 2
5       | 4
6       | 2
```

Here querying is easier: Look the person up in one column and find their friends in the other. However, it looks kind of weird to have all pairs duplicated. And you rely on a trigger, which some people don't like.

A third method is to store numbered friendships:

```
friendship | user_id
-----------+--------
1          | 1
1          | 2
2          | 2
2          | 5
3          | 2
3          | 6
4          | 4
4          | 5
```

This gives both users in the pair equal value. But in order to find friends, you need two passes: find the friendships for a user, find the friends in these friendships. However, the design is very clear and even extensible, i.e. you could have friendships of three four or more users.

No method is really much better than the other.

Comment: I'm not sure who downvoted because your answer is extremely helpful. Thank you for your time. I upvoted for you.